# Something is wrong with CRONTAB

Tags: php, cron

My code works fine when I am testing it by writing following line in terminal

```
php email.php
```

my email get's sent, but after I run it as a CRONTAB, it doesn't work.
My email.php file code is:

```
<?php

require("../includes/config2.php"); 

    $list =query("SELECT email, LastName, FirstName, Day, Month FROM birthday WHERE ReminderDay LIKE ? AND ReminderMonth LIKE ?", date("j"),date("n"));
    foreach ($list as $lis)
        {
        mail("{$lis['email']}",'Birthday reminder',"This is a reminder about coming birthday of {$lis['FirstName']} {$lis['LastName']} on {$lis['Day']}th day of {$lis['Month']}th month");
        }
    mail('laurynasgiriunas@gmail.com','Birthday reminder','6'); 
    ?>
```

Crontab starts working when I comment out everything apart the last mail(...) line in email.php file.
Crontab -l gives:

> - - - - - /usr/bin/php /home/jharvard/vhosts/pset7/public/email.php

I don't understand why it works when "php email.php" is called, but doesn't work then file is opened through Crontab

Comment: Try using an absolute path instead of a relative on in that `require`

Comment: Such a simple mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As notified in a comment, problem was that I used relative path instead of an absolute path